# Counting number of times a name exists in an Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a google sheet with for every day an seperate sheet. Every sheet contains a table with names of persons (who have to do a extra job). Not every sheet contains the same persons and not every person on a sheet have to do an extra job. I want to have an overview of the number of times a person has done an extra job. In that way I can choose who has to do an extra job the next time and everyone has to do more or less equal number of extra josb.

So I want to have a -total- sheet that contains the name of all the persons and next to each name the number of times he/she did an extra job, counted **over all the sheets**.

I guess this isn't possible with formulas. Unfortunatly I'm a dummy in scripting.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Wfr
Brian

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible with GS vanilla only.

I tried for fun and for self learning purpose:

[image: Example]

[[What's inside a day sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYGlq.png)]

As you haven't given many details, you will have to adapt my formulas to your spreadsheet

**First Step: List all names in -TOTAL-!B3**

```
=let(_getDate,lambda(d,TEXT(DAY(d),"00")&"/"&TEXT(MONTH(d),"00")&"/"&YEAR(d)),
Γ,tocol(map(SEQUENCE(F3-E3,1,0,1),
lambda(d,torow(iferror(indirect(_getDate(d+E3)&"!B3:B"),""),1))),1),unique(filter(Γ,not(Γ=""))))
```

**Second Step: Count all extra jobs/unique names in -TOTAL-!C3** (with help of the list we just build) :

Unfortunatly I still have'nt succeed doing this part, the best I did is counting times different names appear. This must be close, maybe try something with **REDUCE**.
You could try to solve this out, or  someone better might edit this response.

**-EDIT-**

For now you can try to solve this second step out by using this sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMklKgPUANCifyWHde_tSzJRAwvFfm105VmgABj0yJM

Comment: Can you send me the files (url) to the sheet you used. I even stuck on step 1 :(

Comment: You can find what you want and adapt it to your project here,, good luck :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76284571/why-does-my-offset-condition-not-work-in-my-google-spreadsheet-formula-offset-w