# Why does my OFFSET condition not work in my Google Spreadsheet formula (OFFSET within FILTER within MAP)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm counting how many times names are appearing in all my daily sheets (sample of daily sheet: "11/05/2023"), but only if a name is associated with a value **TRUE** next to it.
Unfortunately, I'm having an issue using **OFFSET** within a **FILTER** and a **MAP**, it doesn't work as I expected.

*Example:*

[image: Issue]

What's inside a daily sheet
[image]

The following formula help me retreiving in column **B** all names there are in all my daily sheets :

```
=let(_getDate,lambda(d,TEXT(DAY(d),"00")&"/"&TEXT(MONTH(d),"00")&"/"&YEAR(d)),Γ,tocol(map(SEQUENCE(J3-I3,1,1),lambda(d,torow(iferror(indirect(_getDate(d+I3)&"!"&"B3:B"),""),1))),1),Λ,filter(Γ,not(Γ="")),unique(Λ))
```

The following formula counts in column **C** how many times names are appearing :

```
=let(_getDate,lambda(d,TEXT(DAY(d),"00")&"/"&TEXT(MONTH(d),"00")&"/"&YEAR(d)),Γ,tocol(map(SEQUENCE(J3-I3,1,0,1),lambda(d,torow(iferror(indirect(_getDate(d+I3)&"!B3:C"),""),1))),1),Λ,filter(Γ,not(Γ="")),map(B3:B,lambda(name,if(name="",,COUNTA(filter(Λ,Λ=name))))))
```

And here is my issue, in column **D** I would like to count how many times there are **names associated with a value TRUE in daily sheets**.
To do so, I wanted to use the formula just above and add a condition in the filter:

```
filter(Λ,Λ=name)
```

would become

```
filter(Λ,Λ=name,offset(Λ,1,0)=true)
```

This way I would theoretically get what I want.

But as you can see, this condition **offset(Λ,1,0)=true** doesn't work in **FILTER**. My question is : Why? And what can I do to work this out?

Here is my spreadsheet sample : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMklKgPUANCifyWHde_tSzJRAwvFfm105VmgABj0yJM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`offset` strictly works on actual ranges (A2:A6 and so on...) and not on an array output obtained from calculations (in your case `Λ` value)

you can look into:

```
=let(Λ;reduce(wraprows(;2;);index(text(tocol(sequence(days(J3;I3)+1;1;I3;1);1);"dd/mm/yyy"));lambda(a;c;{a;iferror(indirect("'"&c&"'!B:C");wraprows(;2;))}));
        map(B3:B;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;countifs(index(Λ;;1);Σ;index(Λ;;2);true)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Now time to study your solution. I'm improving everytime you aswer my questions!